# Parsing Json array from an object in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

Sorry for the vague title, this is a basic question. I have a json(more of a dict) which looks like this.

```
{
     'The Runaway Dinosaur': 
                            ['11th May 2016 ', ' 12:00am'],
     'Paradox':
                            ['12th Oct 2016 ', ' 12:00am'], 
     'Gorilla Warfare': 
                            ['18th Nov 2015 ', ' 1:00am'], 
     'Trajectory': 
                            ['23rd Mar 2016 ', ' 12:00am']
}
```

So each json object has an array of  2 elements, i want to extract the first element of each object.

I tried the following:-

```
for a in d: #d is the dict where the json is residing
    print a[0]
```

Expected o/p :- 11th May 2016, 12th Oct 2016 ,...

Actual o/p :- T
P
G
T
R
T
F
E
R
T
P
T
T
T
K
M
P
G
F
T
V
F
O
T
T
F
T
R
R
P
F
W
G
R
T
I
S
B
C
K
S
A
F
L
T
F
I
C
T
F
T
E
M
F
W
T

I want to know what mistake am I making & how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to iterate through `dict` you actually iterate through keys (which are strings so you get first character of each string-key) . And you need values. So:

```
for a in d.values():
    print a[0]
```

Comment: Ah ! I knew it that I was making a basic mistake, thanks, will accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

As Yevhen answered, when you iterate over a `dict` as follows

```
for item in some_dict:
```

each `item` is a key of the dictionary. The order is unspecified.

Therefore, with `a[0]`, you are selecting the first letter of the string that is the key of the `dict`.

You have `.items()` (or `.iteritems()` in Python 2), and `.values()` (or `.itervalues()` in Pyhton 2) to choose from.

E.g.,

```
for key, value in some_dict.items():
    print(value[0])
```

Note that you might get an exception thrown on `value[0]` if the returned JSON has an empty array somewhere as value.